# How do I use oauth2 with Flutter?

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, flutter, blackboard

I'm trying to authenticate my users through the blackboard API: https://developer.blackboard.com/portal/displayApi

However, I can't find a good tutorial on using oauth2 with Flutter. (I'm very new to ouath2). Is this possible? If so how or where is a good tutorial?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Google signin uses oauth2 so pretty much any of the tutorials relating to the google api with do.

For eaxample
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-adding-sign-in-with-google-and-phone-authentication-to-your-app-69f681518f9b